# How can I find the analytical solution for this optimization problem?

Tags: optimization

How to find the analytical solution for this optimization problem?
$$
\begin{align}
& \underset{x,y,z}{\text{maximize}} & (1+\frac{x}{1+z})(1+\frac{y}{1+z})\\
& \text{such that} & 0\leq x\leq x^+\\
&& 0\leq y\leq y^+\\
&& 0\leq z\leq z^+\\
&& x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}\\
\end{align}
$$
where $x^+$,$x^+$ and $z^+$ are positive numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(1+\frac{x}{1+z})(1+\frac{y}{1+z})\le (1 + x) (1 +y) \le (1 + x^+)(1 + y^+)$$

The function achieves the maximum at $(x^+, y^+, 0)$